# What happened to the third post credit scene?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, credits, captain-america-civil-war

It was all over the news that ***Captain America: Civil War*** would have 3 post credit scenes. But in the final product we only got 2 post credit scenes: one mid-credit which worked as an epilogue, and one end credit scene which was all about Spider-Man.

But the 3rd one was not there. It was even [speculated that](http://www.blastr.com/2016-4-28/post-credits-scene-captain-america-civil-war-revealed-spoiler) a later release version might have 3 post credit scenes but it didn't happen. Is there any official word on it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[According to Screenrant](http://screenrant.com/captain-america-civil-war-post-credits/) (beware: SPOILERS for future movies):

> the originally planned [**post-credits scene featuring Bruce Banner
>   a.k.a. Hulk**](http://screenrant.com/captain-america-civil-war-post-credits-scene-hulk/) (Mark Ruffalo) would have been shot for the film but
>   instead, as we learned from co-writer Christopher Markus,

I'll put the information regarding the possible appearance in a future movie in spoilers:

> Marvel decided to save the story of where the Hulk is until later (***Thor: Ragnarok***).

The reason the Hulk-featuring teaser scene didn't make the movie is [explained in the linked article](http://screenrant.com/captain-america-civil-war-post-credits-scene-hulk/):

> Christopher Markus, McFeely’s writing partner, explains in [the same interview with HuffPo](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/hulk-cut-from-post-credit-scene-in-captain-america-civil-war_us_570d55aee4b0885fb50e85a1) how Ruffalo almost did have a post-credits cameo:
>
> > “We can clean that up real quickly. Mark Ruffalo shot no scenes. We talked about having Bruce Banner at the very end of the film, and **it just, again, seemed like we’re sticking people in just to stick them in.** He has clearly gone somewhere at the end of ‘Ultron,’ and that’s a story. **Don’t blow it off and put it in a little tiny chunk just to put in a little extra filigree on our movie.** That’s a story.”